# Understanding Divergence Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, intuition, line-integrals

If $D$ is a region to which Green's theorem applies, $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward unit normal vector to $D$, and
$$
\mathbf{F}=M(x, y) \mathbf{i}+N(x, y) \mathbf{j}
$$
is a $C^{1}$ vector field on $D$, then
$$
\oint_{\partial D} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} d s=\iint_{D} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} d A
$$
I am encountering this theorem in my first vector calculus course, so I had
weird confusion in understanding of this equation. First of all, I am writing, what I understand from this equation:

If we calculate the divergence of **F** at every infinitesimal volume in the region D and we calculate the Flux through the boundary ${\partial D}$ ,then they turns out to be same.

But in LHS of the equation we are considering the value of field **F** on the boundaries, since we are  integrating over ${\partial D}$ only whereas in RHS, we are considering the value of **F** at each point inside the region to calculate the divergence over the region. So how are the value of **F** inside the whole region and at just the boundaries can be related in this way?

How can a line integral of projection of field **F** on an outward normal **n** over the boundary can represent integral of the divergence of all infinitesimal volumes in the region?(I am sorry, if I hadn't made my statements precise,Line integrals and Divergence are totally new concepts for me)

Comment: Someone with more time can expand this into an answer (or find a duplicate): but in one dimension lower this is exactly like the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus saying that the integral of  the derivative over an entire interval equals the difference (0d integral) of the original function at just the endpoints. Intuition about "how" is that the internal divergences cancel out, as described in one higher dimension at https://mathinsight.org/divergence_theorem_idea

Comment: Thanks for the link.